# W/System : Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Whenever I do something related to firebase auth or firestore it gives me this message.The flutter app works perfectly but why is this message showing up?

I am new to firebase and flutter please help me fix this.

Comment: "Locale because its value was null" Set up locale in firebase.

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me how to do that

Comment: To tell you how to do that, first I need to get to know how to do that. All programmers work like that. It's all about finding a solution to an issue. It's OK you don't know how to solve an issue, but if you cannot find a solution to that issue, you will lose a job.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a site where everyone will show you everything, first you need to show what did you read about that what did you try to do to fix the issue etc.

Comment: I had the same issue... I had to rebuild the application (not hot-reload!)... now it works